# How to correctly resize barcode generated from libraries in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, zxing, code128, bartender

[image: Consider 2 barcodes generated using Bartender Software & Libraries available in Github for generating code 128]

1. I have generated Code 128 barcode using libraries but when I resize them manually from c# it doesn't scan.
2. I had generated the same value Code 128 in bartender software, I resized and printed it. My scanner scans it perfectly.

I need some help on how do I resize it properly. I tried cloning the libraries and changing the bar width property but couldn't succeed.

Comment: bar code printers can resize codes natively when using ZPL commands. What are you doing exactly. If you are generating a bitmap, it would be best to tell the generator to generate them to the size you need.. This question is lacking suitable information to answer

Comment: It's called pixel hinting

Comment: @00110001 I had passed the width I need, but libraries are not resizing due to large data, like.Width=50, but it generates around 180 px, if I pass small data, it generates the width I want

Comment: @Charlieface can you help me out how can I do that, tried searching on google but not finding any article related to it.

Comment: Have you found your solution ?

Comment: @ Yup, I used TSPL language to generate the barcode and printer automatically resized it for me.

Answer (score -1):

First of all install [GenCode128](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GenCode128/) nuget from nuget package manager and then use the below namespaces and code to generate barcode

```
using GenCode128;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

    static void Main()
    {
        Image myimg = Code128Rendering.MakeBarcodeImage("Barcode Value", 2, true);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            myimg.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            using (var fileStream = File.Create("E:\\Barcode.jpeg"))
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

second parameter in the below code line defines the size of barcode which you can change as per your barcode size requirement.

```
Image myimg = Code128Rendering.MakeBarcodeImage("Barcode Value", 2, true);
```

Comment: Hi Bhavik, I have already tried n tested almost all barcode libs available on nuget but all give width more than I need. Please read things carefully before posting answer.